# JS заменить дубликаты на пустые строки в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, как пройтись по массиву, чтобы заменить дубликаты на пустые строки. Нужно оставить по одному уникальному значению, а дубликаты заменить пустой строкой.

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5];
```

В данном примере массива должно получиться так:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, '', '', '', 5];
```

Comment: используйте доп массив и метод Includes, который будет проверять наличие этого значения в имеющемся массиве (куда будут "перекладываться" значения)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лучше Set

Comment: @Alexey Ten можете показать пример с Set?

Comment: @Александр не будет лучше просто удалить дубликаты ?

Comment: Мдя, в ответах любители квадратичной сложности…

Comment: Вот вам однострочник `res=arr.map(function(v){return this.has(v)?'':(this.add(v),v)},new Set)` 

Comment: @AlexeyTen, прикольно)))

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо! Можете пояснить вот эту часть: (this.add(v),v). Не могу понять, почему именно так, а не просто this.add(v)?

Comment: @Александр, потому что нужно вернуть элемент, а не `Set`

Comment: @Александр, только не нужно такое писать в нормальном коде. Это просто разминка для ума. В нормальном коде нужно писать как в ответе у меня или Qwertiy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5];
const res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (res.includes(arr[i])) {
    res.push('');
  }
  else {
    res.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Вот рабочий, но не самый оптимальный вариант. Думаю, вам подойдет для понимания.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант, надеюсь помог

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for(let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
    if(arr[i] == arr[j]) arr[j] = "";
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант с `Set` и без квадратичной сложности:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5];

const seen = new Set();
const res = arr.map((val) => {
    if (seen.has(val)) {
        return '';
    }
    seen.add(val);
    return val;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: О, я почти такой же написал)

Answer (score 1):

Для эффективной замены (за линейное время) стоит использовать `Set`:

Замена на месте:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5]

var used = new Set()

for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
  if (used.has(a[q])) {
    a[q] = ""
  } else {
    used.add(a[q])
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

С созданием нового массива:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5]

var used = new Set()
var b = a.map(x => used.has(x) ? "" : (used.add(x), x))
console.log(b)
```

И ещё прикольный финт в качестве бонуса:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5]

var i = 0

for (var x of new Set(a)) {
  while (a[i++] !== x) {
    a[i-1] = ""
  }
}

for (; i < a.length; ++i) {
  a[i] = ""
}

console.log(a)
```